# ajv array with union types

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jsonschema, ajv

Suppose I have the following type:

```
type MixedArray = Array<number | string>;
```

And sample data that I'd like to be valid:

```
[ 'dfdf', 9, 0, 'sdfdsf' ]
```

How do I create an ajv `JSONSchemeType` that will validate the expected mixed array?

I have tried the following:

```
import { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv';

const Mixed: JSONSchemaType<MixedArray> = {
    type: 'array',
    items: {
        anyOf: [
            { type: 'number' },
            { type: 'string' },
        ]
    }

};
```

But I receive a typescript error:

> Type '{ anyOf: ({ type: "number"; } | { type: "string"; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'JSONSchemaType<string | number, false>'.

> json-schema.d.ts(34, 5): The expected type comes from property 'items' which is declared here on type 'JSONSchemaType<MixedType, false>'

Comment: Additional research: this may be a limitation of `ajv` at this time: https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1302

Comment: You might want to see if `{ "type": [ "string", "number" ] }` works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I posted my question, I now try to avoid writing union types when possible. For simplicity sake.

But in the example situation (or others where the union can be an advantage), I discovered that you can wish away the type error by typing the union with `any` and the schema will still work as expected (so long as your functions that depend on the schema know that it is a union type, of course):

```
import { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv';

const Mixed: JSONSchemaType<MixedArray> = {
    type: 'array',
    items: {
        anyOf: [
            { type: 'number' },
            { type: 'string' },
        ]
    }

} as any; // <----- add type declaration here
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that your schema is not strongly typed. To that end, I suppose you could extend `JSONSchemaType` to strengthen your definition.

Comment: Since I've written this, I've discovered zod which is a much better schema library imo, and it easily handles mixed arrays.